# Add automatically template after commit my file to CVS

Tags: eclipse, templates, commit, cvs

I want to create automatically templates in my file after i commit it in my CVS. It is possible ? (example: the date or the author).

And is there a way to set my default template in the end of my file ?

Comment: You need to make an attempt at this first and if you encounter problems, you can post a question clearly explaining what you have tried and what error(s) you are getting. But it is also equally important that you do some basic research before posting your question.

Comment: In Eclipse i create this template named "author"  for my files:                                               /**
 * date: ${date}
 * author: ${user}
 */
So when i digit "author" in my file, it show me the date and the user.  Now the goal is that when i commit my file test.sql on my CVS ,  a piece of code containing the date and the author is added to my file.

Comment: Looks like what you're looking for is call Keyword Substitution.